# In code editor of IntelliJ, wrap selected text in double-quote marks

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, double-quotes

In the code editor for [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2019, I want to add a straight double-quote (QUOTATION MARK) to the currently-selected text to make it a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal).

Is there some keystroke or menu item to make this happen?

Comment: The String Manipulation plugin can do that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's under Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys and is called `Surround selection on typing quote or brace`.

[image: Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys]

Comment: Thanks but where is the shortcut ?

Comment: works flawlessly! @FarbodAprin there is no shorcut. Select the text and press quote key

Answer (score 8):

The verified answer is correct, but if you are wondering what the shortcut is for these smart keys, highlight the text you wish to surround and press the key you wish to surround that text with.

Comment: Thanks, this should be added to accepted answer.